# Hypothesis.strategies generate string from date

Tags: python, hypothesis-test, python-hypothesis

I am using hypothesis to test my application and generate random input data for endpoints.
Here is my code:

```
def generate_upload_data():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    start_date = today - relativedelta(months=1)
    return hypothesis.strategies.builds(
        SomeModelClass,
        date=hypothesis.strategies.dates(
            min_value=start_date, max_value=today
        ),
    )
```

This generates date as datetime.date object, but I need it in string format (01.01.2020).
So I need to convert it like

```
random_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

But I can't find any way to do that.
Is it possible to generate string from date in hypothesis?

Comment: try `hypothesis.strategies.dates(...).map(lambda date: date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the docs on adapting strategies](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#adapting-strategies).  As Azat Ibrakov notes above, you can easily convert dates to strings using

```py
hypothesis.strategies.dates(...).map(lambda date: date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
```